# SQL Server query issue...What does this error mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Trying to run:

```
UPDATE dbo.OBCases 
SET CatID = '42' 
WHERE CatID = '2';
```

but I get the following error from SSMS:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateCaseType, Line 14
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What exactly does this mean, and more importantly, what do I do about it?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a trigger on `dbo.OBCases` the table named `UpdateCaseType`? One way to check (if you're unfamiliar), is to expand the node in SSMS next to the table name, and then expand the node next to triggers.

Comment: @Dan - Yes, there is a stored procedure and it is a whole mix of nested SELECT statements.  I am honestly having trouble figuring out what it is doing, but I am guessing the problem is there.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: Yep, someone's written a trigger and *assumed* that `inserted` and/or `deleted` only contains one row. That's a bad assumption and so its a broken trigger.

Comment: @JJAJ It sounds like (as Damien said) it's a bad trigger. If you find lines of SQL in the trigger that look like `where myColumn = (select myColumn from inserted)`, or similar, that would cause the problem when more than 1 row is involved. This question and answer might help. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89340/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-trigger-error-sql-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dan for giving me the clue about the triggers.  It turns out that the triggers were poorly written to begin with.  There was a whole bunch of nested SELECT statements that were returning multiple results.

The original looked something like this:

```
  Update OBCases set CaseTypeID = (select CaseTypeID from  Hospitals where HospID = (select HospID from inserted)) Where CaseID = (Select CaseID from inserted)
```

I had to update them to not include nested SELECT's making them read more like:

```
UPDATE c
    SET c.CaseTypeID = h.CaseTypeID
    FROM OBCases c
    INNER JOIN inserted i on c.CaseID = i.CaseID
    INNER JOIN Hospitals h on i.HospID = h.HospID
    WHERE c.CaseTypeID <> h.CaseTypeID
```

And I was able to run everything normally.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!